# Loader calls onLoadFinished before Activity's onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: android

When an `AsynctaskLoader` is initiated from Activity's `OnCreate()`, it finishes its work and calls `onLoaderFinished()`  before action bar menu is inflated, that is before `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called.

I need to alter some action menu items depending on results of loader. What approach might resolve this ?

UPDATE:
This happens On orientation change. I'm Observing this sequence in debugger:

1. Application Start: `onCreate()` -> `onCreateOptionsMenu()` -> `onLoadFinished()`
2. Rotate to landscape: `onCreate()` -> `onLoadFinished()` -> `onCreateOptionsMenu()`
3. Rotate back to portrait: `onCreate()` -> `onLoadFinished()` -> `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: Pretty much every sentence in your question is wrong. Context menus have nothing to do with `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, have nothing to do with "menu button on old devices", have nothing to do with "action bar on new ones", and so forth.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, I meant Action Bar menu . see the Update

Comment: I just hit the same pothole. This is exactly the behavior I'm seeing. Trying to set a menuitem icon according to some value in the db. How did you solve this?

Comment: @JRun added as other answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular approach avoids invalidating entire menu.

Define one boolean flag, and one MenuItem variable for each item you want to control based on outcomes of loader results:

Let's say you want to enable *New* action only if loader returns any success:

```
private boolean mEnableNew = false;
private MenuItem mItemNew;
```

Save the menu item to variable when menu is created, also, apply state:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.manage_menu, menu);

  mItemNew = menu.findItem(R.id.itm__manage_menu__new);
  mItemNew.setEnabled(mEnableNew);

  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Finally, obtain new settings based on Loader's results, and enable disable menu item:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<BI_Result> loader, Result result) {

    //--If onCreateOptionsMenu is not yet executed,it will use this boolean value when it does
    mEnableNew = result.isSuccess(); 

    //--If onCreateOptionsMenu has executed, we apply state here
    if (mItemNew != null) {
        mItemNew.setEnabled(mEnableNew);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same scenario when trying to call `shareActionProvider.setShareIntent()` in `onLoadFinished()` which was dependent on shareActionProvider being initalized in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

My solution was to scope both my Intent and ShareActionProvider to the Fragment, and then within each method initialize the appropriate field and set the other if it had already been defined. That way it works no matter which is called first without invalidating the menu.

Here's basically what it looks like

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
...
private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;
private Intent shareIntent;
...
```

onCreateOptionsMenu()

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_my_fragment, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
    //in the case where onLoadFinished is called first, simply set the share intent here.
    if (null != shareIntent)
    {
        shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}
```

onLoadFinished()

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

    ... <get some data from cursor> ...

    shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.share_text)+data);

    //shareActionProvider may be null due to onLoadFinished called before onCreateOptionsMenu
    if (null != shareActionProvider)
    {
        shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to alter some action menu items depending on results of loader. What approach might resolve this ?

Your scenarios #2 and #3 should be perfectly fine for you, then. By the time `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called, you have your `Cursor` (or whatever) from your `Loader` and can tailor what you do in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

With regards to scenario #1, have `onCreateOptionsMenu()` do the most likely thing, and if you determine in `onLoadFinished()` that this is incorrect, call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to force another call to `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, I suppose.

Comment: My loader is a dummy (some string data) that's why it finishes fast. But this should be no exception. Also, I Can't use `invalidateOptionsMenu()` as it results in Activity freezing for some time when orientation change occurs. I could make loader thread wait for a flag, but this will be too complicated. As you suggest I'd go ahead with placing check points at both places. Thanks !

Comment: @wingman: "I could make loader thread wait for a flag, but this will be too complicated" -- not to mention that you have no access to the loader thread. `onLoadFinished()` is called on the main application thread in practice today, last I checked.

Comment: You are right. But I have access to `loadInBackground()` which is run in another thread. Other way around, I can delay `onLoadFinished` logic in my Activity too.(This works well.)